# SafariDriver extension is no longer supported so how do you run selenium tests on Safari browser?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

SafariDriver extension is no longer supported so how do you run selenium tests on Safari browser?
What is needed to setup my Safari browser to be able to run Selenium tests?
What desired capabilities do I have to set?
Do I still need an Apple Developer account for my tests to run too?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where do you get the information SafariDriver is not supported on Mojave? The old SafariDriver is not, now they ship it by default. No, you dont need an Apple developer account to run the tests.

According to the Apple webkit documentation [Testing with WebDriver in Safari](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/testing_with_webdriver_in_safari), the driver is located at `/usr/bin/safaridriver`. On my Mojava macOS I confirmed the binary is by default shipped with the operating system.

The Apple documentation also has a code example and some instructions for people whom upgraded their OS. You might need to run `safaridriver --enable` once as sudo.

Read: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/testing_with_webdriver_in_safari